# Cómo finalizar el llamado a arcade.run() en python...?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente programa en python con arcade:

```
import arcade

def main():
    """ Main method """
    game = MyGame(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    game.setup()
    arcade.run()
    print("Fin...!!!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Pero la instrucción **print("Fin...!!!")** de la función **main** nunca se ejecuta..

Por qué...???

Qué se debe hacer para terminar el arcade.run()...???

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: QUé hay en arcade.run()?

Comment: Supongo que `arcade.run()` es un bucle infinito. ://

Answer (score 1):

Se que es algo tarde, pero espero que mi respuesta sirva de todos modos c:

Al ser `arcade.run()` quien controla el bucle principal de la ventana, `print("fin...!!!")` no se ejecutará hasta que el bucle termine.
Hasta donde se, la unica manera de terminar el bucle es que la ventana sea cerrada, tanto por el jugador o por el mismo programa con el comando `arcade.close_window()` (mis pruebas dicen que si usas este comando antes de `arcade.run()`, el loop se iniciará de todos modos).

Sin embargo, recuerda que la ventana de Arcade es internamente una clase derivada de pyglet.window.Window (del modulo Pyglet), por lo que podemos sumar una tercera forma de cerrar la ventana: `tuventana.close()` y es llamado internamente por arcade.close_window. Pero NO recomiendo usarlo, ya que hay cosas que arcade.close_window hace internamente otras cosas además de cerrar la ventana.

Más información:

- [arcade.run](https://arcade.academy/arcade.html#arcade.run)
- [arcade.close_window](https://arcade.academy/arcade.html#arcade.close_window) (puedes ver el código fuente de dicho comando apretando el texto verde que dice "source")